# Removing text in WooCommerce Thank you page

Tags: woocommerce

I'm customising my WooCommerce thank you page.  I'm familiar with filters and hooks, but there's a part (plain text, < p >) that's in my thank you page and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Does this come from a payment processor? Where do I find this piece of text so I can remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While this question isn't really a good fit for SO, I think I can help you.

That message is NOT a built in part of WooCommerce.  I believe you're using a plugin called CCavenue Payment Gateway.  I googled the highlighted phrase to find this.  https://github.com/sunnyluthra/ccavenue-payment-gateway-woocommerce/blob/master/index.php

You can probably hook into the plugin code and override the message.  Put the code for the hook in your child theme functions.php.  Otherwise, if you overwrite the message directly, you'll have to make that change every time you update the plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry if I posted this in the wrong place.  I'm going to have a look at it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step what to do:

### Step 1

You have to understand where this message comes from.

Try to deactivate your plugins one by one (begin with payment gateways plugins) and each time refresh this age and check if the message has been disappeared.

### Step 2

Now we have to figure it out which hook is used to install this message, it could be one of them – `woocommerce_thankyou` or `woocommerce_thankyou_{PAYMENT GATEWAY}`.

Open the WooCommerce template `/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php` and try to comment the mentioned above hooks one by one and look if the message is disappeared.

So, by the end of the 2nd step you have to know which hook is used to display this message and what plugin does this.

### Step 3

Now let's remove it. Search by plugin files for a `woocommerce_thankyou` hook. Once you find it, check what function or class is used to display the message, once you found out it, insert to you functions.php something likes this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'that functions');
```

I hope it helps. And of course you can always hide it with CSS :)

More details about WooCommerce thank you page hooks and templates in this tut https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/thank-you-page.html#add_form